# How to preserver active directory users when demoting domain controller, then reimport into different domain?

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, domain-controller

We actually don't have an domain installation, just 1 server, which is domain controler with local domain TLD. But we want to implement domain, first off changing domain controler name to outside-reachable domain.

Currently this box runs SharePoint. No exchange, no client workstations, no nothing. But SharePoint actually imports users from AD, i'm concerned on what will happen after the domain has changed?

Should it be safe to remove active directory controller and then create new one with the new domain?

When i run `dcpromo` and try to remove active directory, i read that "All user accounts in this domain will be deleted". I would like to preserve created groups (that reside in folder Users) and users (that reside in another, dedicated to them, folder)

How to preserve the users? Will it not harm SharePoint?

Its currently all about 1 server, no more. It couldn't be hard, could it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it sounds like you do have a domain (if you have a domain controller- you have a domain).  A domain is a security context (kerberos, ntlanman etc),so it's not just a set of account names.

This is not a safe or simple operation (if you are currently using domain credentials elsewhere in the organization) as well as issues with sharepoint (and potentially sql).  The solutions all depend on what resources you have available.  You can export the accounts in various ways (however you will lose passwords if you use most of these services) if you have some hardware you can use [ADMT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332(WS.10).aspx) to migrate users.

Sharepoint will be a different but similar set of challenges, however its not nearly as painful read [Upgrade and migration: Stsadm operations (Windows SharePoint Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288939(office.12).aspx) and [A few notes about STSADM –o migrateuser](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=75).

As always, have a backup before any changes to either piece.

Comment: The thing is domain credentials are used nowhere else - just on the services running on the server. And that's just the SharePoint running there.